# using declarations for template function of template base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, using-statement

I want to use a template function of a base class, like this:

```
struct A {
  template <class T> static auto f() { \*code*\ }
};

template <class A_type> struct B : public A_type {

  using A_type::f;

  void g() { auto n = f<int>(); }
};
```

This does not compile however.

```
error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type
      construction
  void g() { auto n = f<int>(); }
                        ~~~^
error: expected expression
  void g() { auto n = f<int>(); }
```

But referencing the base class directly instead of the template does work:

```
struct A {
  template <class T> static auto f() { \*code*\ }
};

template <class A_type> struct B : public A_type {

  using A::f;

  void g() { auto n = f<int>(); }
};
```

Why does the first version not compile and the second does. And what would I need to do differently to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that the `f` in `f<int>()` is a template, hence the error message.

You can do it without the `using` like so:

```
struct A {
    template <class T> static auto f() { /*code*/ }
};

template <class A_type> struct B : public A_type {
    void g() { auto n = A_type::template f<int>(); }
};
```

Comment: And there is no way to explicitly tell it that it is a template? While experimenting I got some message by the compiler about putting 'template' somewhere into the using statement, but I did not know where ad cannot reproduce that hint.

Comment: I didn't find a way. Tried adding template in all places I could, but the root problem seems to be that you can't have templated `using` declarations, and there's aren't function aliases.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I remembered how I got this hit. The hit is `error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'f' as a dependent
      template name
    using A_type::f<int>;`  and I got it by `using A_type::f<int>;` rather than `using A_type::f;`